# How should I merge multiple Async UseCases into a single one?

Tags: rx-java2, android-mvvm, clean-architecture

I am refactoring parts of our code and feel unsure about my reasoning for a specific problem. Our business requirements are the following:

- We have to call 4 network requests separately from different views.
- We have to wait for 4 network requests **to finish** and **start a new network request**.

Previously all that was handled in a single class, which was shared among 4 different views. However, I am unsure if my reasoning was correct. I did it in the following way:

1. I would initialize **4 replay subjects** for each network request to track when network requests will be finished. (I know I could use RxRelay for this kind of logic, but it is not currently an issue to me)

​

```
fun init(){
    firstTrigger : ReplaySubject<Boolean> = ReplaySubject.create()
    secondTrigger : ReplaySubject<Boolean> = ReplaySubject.create()
    thirdTrigger :  ReplaySubject<Boolean> = ReplaySubject.create()
    forthTrigger : ReplaySubject<Boolean> = ReplaySubject.create()
}
```

​

2. Here is an example code of a one from 4 network requests. I trigger the subject after success.

​

```
fun networkRequestNrOne() { 
    firstObservable = apiService.networkRequestNrOne() 

    compositeDisposable.add(firstObservable
    .retryWhenError(5, 1)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
    .subscribe({ 
        success -> first.onNext(true) }, 
        { throwable -> handleError(throwable) })
    ) 
}
```

​

3. Then I have a method, which is called in init of this class. It uses zip operator from RxJava to combine all network requests

​

```
fun observeWhenToFire(): Observable<Boolean> {
        return Observable.zip(firstTrigger, secondTrigger, thirdTrigger,
                forthTrigger,
                Function4<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean> { first, second, third,
                forth ->
                    //handle checking if all are true for example.
                })
    }
```

​

Now I would like to refactor it and create 4 different UseCases for such cases and a new one UseCase, which would include all 4 UseCases and return a merged response.

However, I would still need to use Rx Subjects to handle such a scenario. Every UseCase would take a subject tied to that UseCase **as a parameter**, while UseCase, **which zips all other** UseCases, would **include 4*1 subjects**.

Is there any better way? I even thought about using regular callbacks and it might be even more readable code.  I do use coroutines as well, however this time I don't want to refactor this logic to coroutines, because of our c**ustom retryWhenError extension**, which is quite unique :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your question really, but this might help you.

```
 Completable.merge(
            listOf(
                usecase1.ignoreElement(),
                usecase2.ignoreElement(),
                usecase3.ignoreElement(),
                usecase4.ignoreElement()
            )
        ).andThen(useCase5.ignoreElement())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnComplete { handleSuccess() }
            .doOnError { handleError(it) }
```